# Yii2 enforce 404 or 500 error

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

In my controller's action of Yii2 application suppose the following:

```
public function actionView($i)
{
  if ($i < 20)
  {
    //I want execute error 404
  }
}
```

All what I can to do now is just setting a flash message and redirect to another action. However, I want to generate 404 Page not found response.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you can just throw a 404 not found exception:

```
throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException();
```

Yii error manager will handle that predefined exception and show the appropiate error page.

You can configure / design your error pages editing views/site/error.php

You can read how can customize that page in the following [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/60144-custom-yii2-error-404/)

Comment: Correct. And if you want to specify a status just do `throw new \yii\web\HttpException($status);`

Comment: @Blizz also `HttpException` may have a custom message property i.e 
`\yii\web\HttpException(601, 'Upper case character not found')`

Answer (score 4):

Put this code to call 404 error page.

```
throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException("Your Error Message.");
```